# Java: Adding a text field to a ChangeEvent

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a homework assignment where I have to alter a color selector (it has 3 sliders, RGB and displays the color) so that there are text fields and when a value is typed into the field, it changes the slider as well. I get the basic idea however I'm having trouble finding a solution to text-fields being changed, they'll only work with Action Event. Here's my code

```
package colorchooser;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author -
 */
public class ColorChooser extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ChangeListener, ActionListener{

    private Vector listeners;

    /**
     * Creates new form ColorChooser
     */
    public ColorChooser() {
        initComponents();
        listeners = new Vector();
        sldRed.addChangeListener(this);
        sldGreen.addChangeListener(this);
        sldBlue.addChangeListener(this);
        txtRed.addActionListener(this);

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSetColor;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblBlue;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblGreen;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblRed;
    private javax.swing.JSlider sldBlue;
    private javax.swing.JSlider sldGreen;
    private javax.swing.JSlider sldRed;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBlue;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtGreen;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtRed;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
         int r = sldRed.getValue();
         int g = sldGreen.getValue();
         int b = sldBlue.getValue();
         Color color = new Color(r,g,b);
         fireColorEvent(new ColorEvent(this,color));
         txtRed.setText(Integer.toString(r));
         txtGreen.setText(Integer.toString(g));
         txtBlue.setText(Integer.toString(b));
    }

    public void addColorListener(ColorListener colorListener){
        listeners.addElement(colorListener);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if(ae.getSource()==btnSetColor){
            try
            {
                if(Integer.parseInt(txtRed.getText()) <= 255){
                sldRed.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtRed.getText()));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtRed.setText("0");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error: Please enter a value equal to or less than 255");
                }            


                if(Integer.parseInt(txtBlue.getText()) <= 255){
                sldBlue.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtBlue.getText()));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtBlue.setText("0");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error: Please enter a value equal to or less than 255");
                }                

                if(Integer.parseInt(txtGreen.getText()) <= 255){
                sldGreen.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtGreen.getText()));
                }
                else
                {
                    txtGreen.setText("0");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error: Please enter a value equal to or less than 255");
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error: Please Enter Numbers");
                txtRed.setText("0");
                txtGreen.setText("0");
                txtBlue.setText("0");
                sldRed.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtRed.getText()));
                sldGreen.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtGreen.getText()));
                sldBlue.setValue(Integer.parseInt(txtBlue.getText()));
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see I'm adding change listeners to the sliders but I have to add an action listener to the txtRed because it won't accept addChangeListener. Any ideas on a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with this approach?  That's how this works.  A word of warning though, when you update the state of the `JSlider`, it will trigger a `ChangeEvent`, which will result in a change the text field ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer With action event it'll update when I press enter or hit a button, but I want it to update whenever I type a key

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that can handle a field been changed...

```
protected void fieldWasChanged(JTextField field) {
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
        JSlider slider = null;
        if (field == txtBlue) {
            slider = sldBlue;
        } else if (field == txtRed) {
            slider = sldRed;
        } else if (field == txtGreen) {
            slider = sldGreen;
        }
        if (slider != null) {
            slider.setValue(value);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace(); 
        // Display error message
    }
}
```

Next, create a inner class that implements the `DocumentListener` interface...

```
public class DocumentHandler implements DocumentListener {

    private JTextField field;

    public DocumentHandler(JTextField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    protected void documentUpdated() {
        fieldWasChanged(field);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        documentUpdated();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        documentUpdated();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        documentUpdated();
    }

}
```

This will monitor for changes to the fields underlying `Document` and call your `fieldWasChanged` method...

Next, register each field with this handler...

```
protected void registerDocumentHandler(JTextField field) {
    DocumentHandler handler = new DocumentHandler(field);
    field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(handler);
}

//...

registerDocumentHandler(txtBlue);
registerDocumentHandler(txtRed);
registerDocumentHandler(txtGreen);
```

Now, if you actually tried this, you'd find that the moment you typed something, your UI would become unresponsive and your program would eventually crash with a `StackOverflowException`, this occurs because the `DocumentHandler` is updating the `JSlider`s, which is updating the fields, which is notifying the `DocumentHandler` and ... so on and so forth...

A simply solution is to put in a flag which, while `true` prevents the `DocumentHandler` from notifying the `fieldWasChanged` method...

```
public class DocumentHandler implements DocumentListener {

    private JTextField field;
    private boolean isUpdating;

    public DocumentHandler(JTextField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    protected void documentUpdated() {
        if (!isUpdating) {
            try {
                fieldWasChanged(field);
            } finally {
                isUpdating = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //...
```

Now you can type and get real time feedback, you can paste text into the fields and they will update the sliders...

Now, having said all that, I encourage you to try using `JFormattedTextField` or `JSlider` instead of `JTextField` as they can help validate the data themselves.  See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details.

If you don't want to use those, but still wish to restrict the user to only been able to enter numbers, have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)